# Share variables - two queues

Tags: tensorflow

Thanks to [Tensorflow multithreading image loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803697/tensorflow-multithreading-image-loading), I have this load data function which, given a csv file e.g. a training csv file it creates some data nodes;

```
 34 def loadData(csvPath,shape, batchSize=10,batchCapacity=40,nThreads=16):
 35     path, label = readCsv(csvPath)
 36     labelOh = oneHot(idx=label)
 37     pathRe = tf.reshape(path,[1])
 38     
 39     # Define subgraph to take filename, read filename, decode and enqueue
 40     image_bytes = tf.read_file(path)
 41     decoded_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_bytes)
 42     decoded_img = prepImg(decoded_img,shape=shape)
 43     imageQ = tf.FIFOQueue(128,[tf.float32,tf.float32,tf.string], shapes = [shape,[447],[1]])
 44     enQ_op = imageQ.enqueue([decoded_img,labelOh,pathRe])
 45     
 46     NUM_THREADS = nThreads
 47     Q = tf.train.QueueRunner(
 48             imageQ,
 49             [enQ_op]*NUM_THREADS,
 50             imageQ.close(),
 51             imageQ.close(cancel_pending_enqueues=True)
 52             )
 53 
 54     tf.train.add_queue_runner(Q)
 55     dQ = imageQ.dequeue()
 56     X, Y, Ypaths = tf.train.batch(dQ, batch_size = batchSize, capacity = batchCapacity)
 57     return X, Y, Ypaths
```

I then call it and have the standard model, loss, train subgraphs such as;

```
xTr, yTr, yPathsTr = loadData(trainCsvPath, *args)
yPredTr = model1(xTr,*args)
ce = ... # some loss function
learningRate = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
trainStep = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learningRate).minimize(ce)
```

I then proceed to train the weights in model. As I understand so far I don't need to have data fed into `feed_dict` as it is already defined.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
     coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
     threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess,coord=coord)
     while not coord.should_stop(): 
           sess.run([trainStep],feed_dict={learningRate:lr})
```

My question is now;

What's the best way to incorporate a train/test process? I.e. once the threads have finished the train csv file they then read the test csv file and I run another session where I have something like;

```
xTe, yTe, yPathsTe = loadData(csvPathTe, *args)
yPredTe = model1(xTe,*args) #will this use the same weights as the trained network? Or am I defining another seperate subgraph?
ce = ... # redefined for yPredTe
while not coord.should_stop(): 
      ce.eval() # return losses
```

which runs until the test csv file has finished.

How would I then rinse and repeat these steps (possibly shuffling my training set) for a set number of epochs? Should I have a csv queue as well?

Answer (score 3):

Alas, currently there is no good answer to this question. The typical evaluation workflow involves running a **separate process** that periodically does the following (e.g. [`evaluate()` in `cifar10_eval.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/12f279d6f4cb33574bc20109b41eb8a59f40cfd1/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_eval.py#L116)):

1. Build a graph that includes an input pipeline that knows about the evaluation set, a copy of the model, the evaluation ops (if any), and a `tf.train.Saver`.
2. Create a new session.
3. Restore the latest checkpoint written by the training process in that session.
4. Run the test op (e.g. `ce` in your question) and accumulate the results in Python, until you get a `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError`.

We're currently working on improved input pipelines that will make it easier to iterate over files many times, and reuse the same session.

Comment: Okay so I can just loop over two separate sessions (one train and one test) for the amount of epochs desired?

Comment: That would work, yes. It might be easier to use a sequence of different sessions for test, so that you can use the `tf.errors.OutOfRangeError` to detect when you have processed the entire test set.

Comment: Do I have to init the last object? E.g. do I give the ```tf.errors.OutOfRangeError``` init argument a reader node like ```reader = tf.TextLineReader(skip_header_lines=1) ```?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... I was suggesting that you wrap your eval code (in particular, the loop that calls `sess.run()`) in a `try:`/`except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:` block. TensorFlow will raise this exception when the input has been exhausted. (There are also higher-level wrappers, such as [`tf.train.MonitoredSession`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/distributed_execution#MonitoredSession) that catch this exception for you.)

Comment: I can't seem to get the queue to throw that error it just loops back to the beginning I believe. Is there something you think I might be missing?

Comment: The bug might be in the implementation of the `readCsv()` function. I was assuming it used something like `tf.string_input_producer(..., num_epochs=1)` but it might be defaulting to `num_epochs=None` (which means it will loop indefinitely).

Comment: On a larger csv file I think my threads are not coordinating and it just breaks as soon as one of them is finished maybe? e.g. on a csv of size 100 i get through the first 64 before it breaks (with 16 threads).