# feed picture to model tensorflow for training

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to import pictures to my model for training just like example "**image_retraining**" :
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining 
but the import process image is in the **classify_image_graph_def.pb** so I don't know how it works

I found these ways:
[Tensorflow multithreading image loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803697/tensorflow-multithreading-image-loading/40985375#40985375)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36947632/7040568

https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-workshop/blob/master/04%20Feedforward%20Network.ipynb

Would you mind telling me which is the standard way of tensorflow to import pictures for training model ?
I haven't used `tf.train.batch` , `tf.train.Coordinator` and `tf.train.start_queue_runners` yet.

I really confused cause I'm still learning how to use tensorflow so I just need a simple or the standard way

thank you and regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to load them yourself using PIL or OpenCV e.g. `cv2.imread(filename.png)`, and then give them to your graph (in `feed_dict`) as an array with dimensions [`number of images (batch size), height, width, channels (3 if RGB)]`.

Comment: I'm not sure - does it run?

Comment: `image_data = ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float)

image_data = (image_data - 255/ 2) / (255/ 2)`


is it right ?

Comment: yes, but i'm not sure about
 image_data = (image_data - 255/ 2) / (255/ 2)

Comment: So that subtracts 127.5 from the image, and then divides by 127.5. I guess that sets your images to be between -1 and 1. I think I have read that "whitening" your data like that is a good idea. You may want to subtract the actual mean of the data (or of each channel or something) and then divide by the max. I don't know what is best.

Comment: do you know any architecture or model for OCR using neural network ?. I mean I want to recognize each letters and numbers (0-9 , a-z)  but I always found result of mnist digits. Another question: the return of tf.decode_jpg and  ndimage.imread is the same ,right ?

Comment: I would be googling for one like you at this point. :) Sorry. I'm not sure if they are the same. You can check real quick and see.